# Visual Studio: The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 129

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio on a device running Linux Mint but whenever I try and run a c# program in visual studio It throws up the error

`The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 129.`

It gives me the option to **Debug Anyway** but then it says:

`No executable found matching command "dotnet-/home/XXXX/Documents/C# Practice/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/HelloWorld.dll"`

(The XXXX is just simply as I do not wish to share my name)

Here Is the **launch.json** file

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/HelloWorld.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/HelloWorld.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "xdg-open"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

}

Here is the **tasks.json** file

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What happens if you run `dotnet build` from the command line?

Comment: If I run `dotnet build`it says: error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: First guess would be that you have a Unicode BOM at the start of your project file. Open it in VS Code and make sure the status bar doesn't mention BOM anywhere. Also you may want to not suppress the output of your build command.

Comment: How do I make sure I'm not suppressing the output of the build command?

Comment: `presentation > reveal > silent` is suppressing the build output. I think you can remove the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

If the task is for build like my case you just have to add the missing part of the command for dotnet `("command": "dotnet") -> ("command": "dotnet build")`, or whatever task that you want to make.

My task in JSON:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "taskName": "build",
        "command": "dotnet build",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": silent"
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
}
```

Comment: Hi Guys , I am also facing the same error . Is there any solution. However, for me the "dotnet build" work fine from command prompt.